# Magento 2 AMP page: Custom JavaScript is not allowed

Tags: magento, amp-html

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-lightbox-0.1.js"></script>
```

I am using this tag in magento2 layout default.xml file and using `<amp-lightbox>`. But in google search console getting the error

> Custom JavaScript is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're missing the `custom-element` attribute on your `<script>`.

Try using this:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-lightbox" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-lightbox-0.1.js"></script>
```